# WordPress plugin to return 404 for some pages base on url attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-404

I need to return 404 for some pages base on url attributes 
For example user enter 
`myblog.com/websites/` he gets normal response (code 200)
If he enter some special parameters like `/?no_redirect=true`

`myblog.com/websites/?no_redirect=true`

Than I would like to return 404 page not found.
I need all this to clean my SEO from some unwanted links

I found this plugin "404 Redirected" where I can select type of Redirect like 301, any body knows where I can add type return 404.

Comment: have you tried : "myblog.com/websites?no_redirect=true" removing the '/'

Comment: It is just an example of link, but it is important for me to create 404 on exactly link I what.